# Sencha style checkbox with specific class

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, checkbox

I have tried styling my checkbox which has a class "checkBox" applied but no succes.
Where am I wrong?

```
.checkBox .x-input-checkbox:checked  + .x-field-mask:after  {
    content: "";
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;

    background-image:url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/48/checkbox_checked.png);
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
}

.checkBox .x-input-checkbox  + .x-field-mask:after {
    content: "";
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;

    background-image:url(http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/48/checkbox_unchecked.png);
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
}

<input type="button" id="markModeCheckbox-inputEl" role="checkbox" class="x-form-field x-form-checkbox x-form-cb  " autocomplete="off" hidefocus="true" data-errorqtip="">
<label id="markModeCheckbox-boxLabelEl" class="x-form-cb-label x-form-cb-label-after" for="markModeCheckbox-inputEl">Box Label</label>
```

I am going to have multiple checkboxes which I want to style different depending on id or class

Comment: Use the DOM inspector, it's no different to any other CSS.

Comment: Are you trying to apply these styles directly to the checkbox?  Ya can't use `:after { content: ''; }` on inputs.  Can you please post your markup?

Comment: The markup is generated!

Comment: Neither of those elements has a class of `checkBox`.  Can you put together a Fiddle?

Comment: That something else that is puzzling me. But I am just wondering what is the correct syntax of the selectors.

Comment: The way you've got it set up at the moment, only children of the `.checkBox` class will be selected.

Comment: well the id is set which might be even better

Comment: Changing the first selector to .x-form-field ...
Did not help either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use a DOM inspector like Firebug or the Chrome Developer Tools. Having a look at the DOM which is generated by ExtJS:

```
<table class="x-field checkBox x-table-plain x-form-item x-form-type-checkbox x-field-default x-border-box" cellpadding="0" id="checkboxfield-1009" style="table-layout: auto;">
    <tbody>
        <tr role="presentation" id="checkboxfield-1009-inputRow" class="x-form-item-input-row">
            <td role="presentation" id="checkboxfield-1009-labelCell" style="" valign="top" halign="left" width="105" class="x-field-label-cell">
                <label id="checkboxfield-1009-labelEl" for="checkboxfield-1009-inputEl" class="x-form-item-label x-unselectable x-form-item-label-left" style="width:100px;margin-right:5px;" unselectable="on">My Checkbox:</label>
            </td>
            <td role="presentation" class="x-form-item-body  x-form-cb-wrap" id="checkboxfield-1009-bodyEl" colspan="2">
                <input type="button" id="checkboxfield-1009-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-checkbox x-form-cb" autocomplete="off" hidefocus="true" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

...the CSS selectors are quite obvious and very simple:

```
.checkBox .x-form-checkbox {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background-image: url(http://png-2.findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/48/checkbox_unchecked.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.checkBox.x-form-cb-checked .x-form-checkbox {
    background-image: url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2232/wireframe_mono/48/checkbox_checked.png);
}
```

Note, that you cannot use the `:checked` pseudo-class, since the input type is button, not checkbox.

However, you can use the CSS class `.x-form-cb-checked` which is applied when the checkbox is checked.

Also see [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2qt) (with ExtJS 4.2.1, since you did not state which version you are using)

Comment: Now the label is gone? How can I also style the label so there is some text over the checkbox

Comment: .checkBox .x-form-checkbox  + .checkBox:after{
content: 'text over';
}

This sadly doesn't work

Comment: What's wrong with the [fieldLabel](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-cfg-fieldLabel) property? Why do you want to add this with CSS?

Comment: Because I have styled the checkbox to look like a button

Comment: Well, the selector for the label is `.checkBox label` so you apply any styles there. I'm not exactly sure how you want it to look though, so you might want to describe more precisely what you want to achieve if you need further help.