# ExtJs. How to set CSS for checkbox in fieldpanel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I need to change the sight of checkbox in a fieldpanel. But I haven't found where I can set css style for it.
My code looks like this

```
{
     xtype: 'fieldset'
     ,title:'<font size="3"><spring:message code="title"/></font>'
     ,collapsible:true
     ,checkboxToggle: true
     ,collapsed: true
     ,margin: 5
     ,border: 0
     ,items: [{..}] 
}
```

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

What I need:
[image: what I need]

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Can you give a screenshot of how you want the checkbox to be ? Both fieldset and checkbox has cls as a property where you can specify the styleclass.

Comment: I've attached the screenshot how it looks now. The first and the third checkboxes from fieldset. I need to make them as my second checkbox. I guess there is only way to do it - to not use fieldset because when I tried to add css property to fieldset it changed the frame sigh.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I could come up with. Use fieldset with checkboxgroup.  If you inpect the dom layout of checkbox, you will see that it is of type button with background image of repeated checkboxes. Hence if you want to change the style of checkbox you will have to change the background image also.

```
{                   
                xtype:'fieldset',
                columnWidth: 0.5,
                title: 'Fieldset 1',
                collapsible: true,                
                defaults: {anchor: '100%'},
                layout: 'anchor',
                items :[
                        {
                            xtype: 'checkboxgroup',                         
                            // Arrange checkboxes into one column, distributed vertically
                            cls : 'checkboxOverride',                               
                            columns: 1,
                            vertical: true,
                            items: [
                                { boxLabel: 'Item 1', name: 'rb', inputValue: '1' },
                                { boxLabel: 'Item 2', name: 'rb', inputValue: '2', checked: true },
                                { boxLabel: 'Item 3', name: 'rb', inputValue: '3' }                                 
                            ]
                        }
                    ]

        }
```

In CSS add,

```
.checkboxOverride{
    border-color: blue; 
}

.checkboxOverride .x-form-checkbox{
    border-color: blue; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url("checkbox_unchecked.png");    
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.checkboxOverride .x-form-field{
    color: blue;

}
.checkboxOverride .x-form-cb-checked .x-form-checkbox {
    background-image: url("checkbox_checked.png");
    background-position: 0 0px;
}
```

Result will look like

[image: Result]

Thanks to [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252229/sencha-style-checkbox-with-specific-class)

Comment: Thanks. I see what you mean, but in this case that would be 3 checkboxes, but I need to make filesets instead of the first and third checkboxes (when I click on them should open a panel). 
I added the picture what I need.