# Styling checkbox added to header

Tags: extjs

I have a grid panel with a checkbox added in its header.
How can I stylize the checkbox?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.SalesTour', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    controller: 'salestour',
    title: 'List of SalesTour',
    iconCls: 'x-fa fa-handshake-o',
    store: 'MyApp.store.SalesTourStore',
    columnLines: true,

    header: 
    {
        xtype: 'header',
        titlePosition: 0,
        defaults: {
            margin: '0 10px'
        },
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            //labelStyle: 'color: #FFFFFF',
            //style: 'color: #FFFFFF',
            boxLabel: 'Hide converted',
            name: 'hideConverted',
            inputValue: true,
            checked: true
        }],
        listeners: {
            beforerender: 'onBeforeHeaderRender'
        }
    },

    columns: [
    {
    ...
    ...
```

I tried using **labelStyle** and **style** properties unsuccessfully...
I would expect to see the checkbox and its label of white color.

Some suggestion, please? What can I do?

Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: where is your combobox. I can't see it anywhere!

Comment: thanks! It was a mistake, I meant "checkbox" ... I already updated the post

Comment: may be this thread will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252229/sencha-style-checkbox-with-specific-class

Comment: Are you trying to change checkbox image or boxLabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add css classes to the checkbox.

**For Example**

You could create a css class

```
   .boxLabel-font-white {
      color: white;
   }
```

And add the class to the config boxLabelCls to color the boxLabel for the checkbox.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html#cfg-boxLabelCls

There are many more cls-configs you could use:
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Checkbox.html

I hope that helps